# data-only React component that can affect state-based re-rendering?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React, so forgive the newbie question.

I've got a plain ol' JS object that wraps a WebSocket and exposes state based on the messages it's received over the socket, e.g. the current set of messages in a chat. In Angular or Polymer (or WinForms and WPF), when new data comes in, I'd send a notification using a standard protocol to let data bound clients know that the state has changed and re-rendering would happen for those clients.

I'd do the same thing in this case by extending React.Component in my WS wrapper class, except that it's got no UI (it's just a cache of the state gleaned from the messages flowing over the WS), so it would return null from render and I'm not clear on whether it stays in the DOM or not at that point. Further, I'm not sure how to make UI from a parent or peer element of the WS wrapper object update as it's state changes.

What's the React way to have a data-only component? I'm trying to get my head around React before I dive into Redux, so hopefully the answer here doesn't require picking up a Flux implementation.

Thanks!

Comment: Wait.. no rendering? What's the point of using React?

Comment: I think you might be confused about what React is for. It's only purpose is to render stuff as an effect of state changes (which may or may not be state that belongs to your React application tree)

Comment: I understand what React is for -- what I've got is a plain o' JS object with state in it that I'd like to use to cause a re-render of the portion of the React tree showing that state. If the POJO isn't a React Component, how do I make that happen?

Comment: call ReactDOM.render whenever that state changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the wrapper JS object should be the App "global" state. Regardless of where you contain it in React (a top-level component with vanilla React, or a store in Redux).

Assuming that you put it as the state of a top-level component, then when new data comes in, all you need to do is `setState(newData)`

All UI driven by this data should be described within that top-level component that holds the state. All children components can be read-only.

When the top-level component changes its state, all children will be re-rendered with new read-only props.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of needing to call `setState`, can just call `ReactDOM.render` every time external state changes (which is close enough to what redux is doing)